# Saving separate CSVs for each queried list item

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, beautifulsoup

I am new to Python and working on a web scraping script that has a list of sites and each time the script queries a site from the list, I need it to save to a separate CSV.

Currently, it seems to iterate each site on my list but only saves to the CSV, the items from the very last query (`www.website.com/3`). I realize once it loops through my `records` list, it gets reset, but shouldn't it save the CSV first? Unless the file is just being overwritten with new data, but if that's the case, how do I increment the file names for each query?

```
from typing import Counter
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys
import csv

pages = [
    'https://www.website.com/1',
    'https://www.website.com/2',
    'https://www.website.com/3'
]

for page in pages:
    r = requests.get(page)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    productName = soup.find_all('div',class_='name')
    productID = soup.find_all('span', id='product_id')
    productCost = soup.find_all('span', class_='regular-price')

    records=[]
    for item in range(len(productName)):
        records.append({
            'name': productName[item].find('a').text.strip(),
            'product_ID': productID[item].text.strip(),
            'price': float(productCost[item].text.strip()[1:].replace(",",""))
            })

    with open("filename.csv", 'w', newline='') as outfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=records[0].keys())

        writer.writeheader()
        for record in records:
            writer.writerow(record)
```

Comment: Sure, it saves the CSV, and the next time through the loop you open it again, which erases the previous contents.  Were you expecting it to append the data?  You can certainly do that by using `'a'` instead of `'w'`.  Or, you can keep a counter and do `open(f"filename{counter}.csv",'w')`.

Comment: @Tim Roberts: It's not as simple as opening the file in `'a'` append mode when using `csv.DictWriter` because it will automatically will add an unwanted header row in the middle of the file.

Comment: Absolutely correct.  I was hoping to lead the OP into understanding the behavior he is seeing by contrasting with `'a'`.

Comment: ch11nV11n: What do you want to name these separate CSV files?

Comment: @martineau I ideally would like to save each file appending a value on the end. Or even appending the contents of each query to the next available row in a single file would work.

Comment: Well, for the first option @DebashisDeb's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68686943/355230) (possibly plus what's in my comment below it) should work.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how would you go about appending the secondary query results to the file created by the first query and add those to the next available row in that file?

Comment: Actually, what I said earlier was wrong, so you *could* reopen the same file in append mode to add data to it as long as it had the same fieldnames. Header rows are only written when the `DictWriter.writeheader()` method is called explicitly — something I thought happened automatically. My apologies to @Tim Roberts.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're correct, the file contents are getting overwritten here.
There are many ways to get around this limitation, the simple one would be to maybe attach an integer value to the file name so that it is easy to interpret.

```
file_name = f'filename-{value}.csv'
with open(file_name, 'w', newline='') as outfile:
   ... your write logic goes here ...
   ... 
value = value + 1
```

You can initialize the `value` variable at the top by 0 (`value = 0`).
What I've used while creating the file_name variable is called `f-strings` in python, they help you with putting dynamic content in a string.

Comment: A simple way to get a numeric `value` to use would be to change the outer `for` loop to: `for value, page in enumerate(pages, start=1):`.